# Flutter - FileSystemException: Creation failed flutter_build, permission denied

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to run my Flutter app. It worked well before, I don't know what happened but now it just won't launch.

When I try to launch it from Android Studio, I get :

```
Crash report sent (report ID: [crash id])
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Crash report written to /home/my_project_path/flutter_07.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
```

When I try to launch it with `flutter run` I get the same thing.

`flutter doctor` runs well, and I get no error :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Linux, locale fr_FR.UTF-8)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

The main exception given in the flutter_07.log is :

`FileSystemException: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/home/revan/Programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-2.4.0/pubspec.yaml' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)`

I tried to `sudo chmod 777 /home/revan/Programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-2.4.0/pubspec.yaml` and it seemed to work, as when I re-run flutter run, it is another `pubspec.yaml` file in one of the library in `.pub_cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org` that lacks of permission.

I guess I could `chmod` manually `pubspec.yaml` of all my 341 libs available in this directory, however it would take a long time and I guess this is not the right method to do it.

Any idea ?

EDIT :
Okay, so I launched following command :
`sudo find **/pubspec.yaml -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

It seems to work, as now I have another error :

`FileSystemException: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'my_project_path/.dart_tool/flutter_build' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)`

Answer (score 0):

So after reading the logs, I also had an error about ADB server not using the ADB client version. With the command `which adb` I saw that I was not using the same adb as in my `${ANDROID_SDK_PATH}/platform-tools/adb`.

I copied my `${ANDROID_SDK_PATH}/platform-tools/adb` in place of my `/usr/bin/adb`

Then the issue transformed in an Android SDK error.
The logs said that I used `usr/lib/android-sdk/`, but the Android SDK I was using before was in `~/Program`. I replaced every directory in `/usr/lib/android-sdk/` with the directories I had in my `~/Programs` (`build-tools` ; `licenses` ; `platforms` ; `platform-tools` ; `tools`).

Now it is working ; but I am aware I should not have fixed it like that. It's kinda dirty and dangerous to copy files in the system binaries directories.

If you have better ideas, feel free to answer this question for next people with this issue.